# Image in tooltip using bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, frontend

```
<button title="Tooltip on right" data-placement="right" data-toggle="tooltip" class="btn btn-default mrs" type="button">Tooltip on right</button>


<script>
  $(function () {
    $('[data-toggle=tooltip]').tooltip();
  });
</script>
```

This works fine but I'd like to include an image and some text inside the tooltip. I tried to use data-content="some stuff" but it shows nothing.

Comment: Please give us the code for what `.tooltip()` does, as well as more code in general. Maybe make a [fiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net)

Comment: read the docs on how to set html and content template

Comment: I've tried to use <template></template> and then add data-cotent="mytemplateid"...
You can find about .tooltip() [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_tooltip_plugin.htm)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You have to pass in the html option to when you initialize .tooltip.
e.g.

```
<div class="cart"> 
    <a data-toggle="tooltip" title="<img src='http://getbootstrap.com/apple-touch-icon.png' />">
        <i class="icon-shopping-cart"></i>
    </a>
```

```
$('a[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({
    animated: 'fade',
    placement: 'bottom',
    html: true
});
```

See the example [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/joshvito/v4p24ak8/1/)

Comment: Thank you, didn't know that. Is there a way to pass content in other place than title? I'm trying with data-content but it doesn't work

Comment: you should check the documentation on the bootstrap site. http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips-options In your case, I would use a template and add your image with css.

Comment: Indeed, so popover has the data-content attribute but not tooltip

Comment: @dkx22 yes, that seems to be the case;